# Spectral Mapping Theorem

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Spectral mapping theorem is as follows:
https://math.uc.edu/~halpern/Matrix.methods/Homatrixmethods/Spectralmappingthm.pdf

> > Is Spectral mapping theorem true for point spectrum ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reference is talking about matrices.  Which spectral mapping theorem are you interested in?  For example, here's one version (see e.g. Rudin, "Functional Analysis", theorems 10.28 and 10.33):

Suppose $T$ is a bounded linear operator on the complex Banach space $X$, $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb C$ open with $\sigma(T) \subset \Omega$, and $f$ analytic in $\Omega$.  Then the holomorphic functional calculus defines $f(T)$ such that, among other things (where $\sigma_p$ denotes point spectrum):

1. $f(\sigma(T)) = \sigma(f(T))$
2. $f(\sigma_p(T)) \subseteq \sigma_p(f(T))$
3. If there is no connected component of $\Omega$ on which $f$ is constant, then $f(\sigma_p(T)) = \sigma_p(f(T))$.

However, without that restriction the statement would be false.  Consider e.g.
an operator $T$ which has no point spectrum, and let $f$ be identically $0$.
Then $\sigma_p(f(T)) = \sigma_p(0) = \{0\}$, but $f(\sigma_p(T)) = \emptyset$.

Comment: If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ of complex coefficient, then does $(3)$ hold ?

Comment: Sorry I meant to say,
If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ of complex coefficient, then does $(3)$ hold without the "connected" condition?

Comment: If $n \ge  1$, $f$ is not constant on any open set, so yes.  A polynomial of degree $0$ is constant.

Comment: It is true that $f$ is not constant in an open set if $f$ is a polynomial. But how can we be sure that $f$ is not constant in a connected set ? 
Because every connected set is not open.

Comment: $\Omega$ is open, so its connected components are open.  A polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$ takes any given value in at most $n$ different points.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are two bounded linear operator on a Banach space, whose spectrum and point spectrum are known, then what can we say about the spectrum and point spectrum of $A+B$ and $AB$

Comment: This should be a new question, not a comment